# Probability of finding the argmax over inner products

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $U(\mathbb{S}^{d-1})$ be the uniform probability over the unit sphere. Given $x_1,\dots,x_d, a,b\in \mathbb{R}^d$, I'm looking at the following probability:

$$P(\mathcal{X},a,b) = \text{Pr}_{y\sim U(\mathbb{S}^{d-1})}\left[ \operatorname{argmax}_{x_i\in \mathcal{X}}\, \langle x_i,a\rangle \cdot \langle y,b\rangle  = \operatorname{argmax}_{x_i \in \mathcal{X}}\, \langle x_i,y\rangle\right]\,,$$

where I write $ \mathcal{X} = \{x_1,\dots,x_d\}$ for short.
I want to show essentially that for the best $a,b$ that are picked without knowing $X$, this probability is almost uniform. More concretely, I would like to prove:

$$\max_{a,b}\,\, \mathbb{E}_{x_1,\dots,x_d\sim  U(\mathbb{S}^{d-1})} \,\,P(\mathcal{X},a,b) \leq \frac{1}{d} + O\left(\frac{1}{\exp(d)}\right)$$

As a follow-up question, suppose that we consider $A,B\in \mathbb{R}^{d\times r}$ for $r\leq d$. How does this probability behave, where we consider:
$$P'(\mathcal{X},A,B) = \text{Pr}_{y\sim U(\mathbb{S}^{d-1})}\left[ \operatorname{argmax}_{x_i\in \mathcal{X}}\, x_i^\top A B^\top y  = \operatorname{argmax}_{x_i\in \mathcal{X}}\, \langle x_i,y\rangle\right]\,,$$
and
$$\max_{A,B}\,\,\mathbb{E}_{x_1,\dots,x_d\sim  U(\mathbb{S}^{d-1})} \,\,P'(\mathcal{X},A,B)$$

Comment: can you show what have you tried?

Comment: I think that I can show that if a and b are chosen after X is known then this probability is at least 1/d + 1/poly(d), by a "good" choice of a and b. 
The problem is when X is not known. My thoughts were to construct a reduction to some computationally hard problem, where finding "good" a,b would also solve the problem and thus condition the result on some computational assumption (e.g. p != np). However, I'm not sure which problem to choose.